# HTTP not accessible on laptop connected to Hotspot?

Tags: wi-fi

I have the $60 unlimited MetroPCS LTE plan. The hotspot works on my laptop and MP3 player, but I can't browse websites that aren't in secure mode on the laptop. Are they blocking port 80, or is there something else I can do to configure this?

The phone is not rooted, and also it's not malware-related or a network misconfiguration on my laptop. HTTP mode works fine when connected to other networks.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused with your question. You talk about your laptop and MP3 player. Then later you talk about your phone and laptop. [In any case, I think this is not an Android issue, but your WiFi, since you say you can browse non-secure websites using other networks]

Comment: What confuses you? I have my MP3 player using my phone's hotspot for internet. I also have my laptop using the same hotspot. I just brought up my MP3 player to eliminate the prospects of someone saying the hotspot isn't working. My laptop browsing via other networks eliminates the prospects of the laptop network card being culprit.